# How to read data from multiple mongodb collections using pyspark?

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a mongo db with multiple collections (let's say 3). I want to join them all so that I can do some aggregations. I was able to connect to a local db and one collection using documentation found oneline but I want to be able to read multiple collections.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
my_spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("myApp") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:3.0.1") \
    .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/mydb.collA") \
    .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/mydb.output") \
    .getOrCreate()
df = my_spark.read.format("mongo").load()
df.printSchema()
```

The above code lets me read `collA` into a df. but I want to also be able to read `collB`, `collC` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the source collection as part of the `spark.read`:

```
val df: DataFrame = spark.read
 .format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource")
 .option("spark.mongodb.input.uri", mongoUri)
 .option("spark.mongodb.input.database", dbName)
 .option("collection", collectionName)
 .load()
```

If the collections are schema compatible, you can union them in the following way:

```
val collections = Seq("collA", "collB", "collC")
collections.map { collection => 
  spark.read
     .format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource")
     .option("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1")
     .option("spark.mongodb.input.database", "mydb")
     .option("collection", collection)
     .load()
    }.reduce(_ union _)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a list of URIs into the spark.mongodb.input.uri config.

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

my_spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("myApp") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:3.0.1") \
    .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/mydb.collA, mongodb://127.0.0.1/mydb.collB, mongodb://127.0.0.1/mydb.collC") \
    .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/mydb.output") \
    .getOrCreate()

df_collA = my_spark.read.format("mongo").load()
df_collB = my_spark.read.format("mongo").option("collection", "collB").load()
df_collC = my_spark.read.format("mongo").option("collection", "collC").load()

df_collA.printSchema()
df_collB.printSchema()
df_collC.printSchema()
```

The first one is the default, but swithing the collection option before the load can lead you into the other collections as well. [Source](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/spark-connector/v2.4/configuration/#std-label-spark-input-conf)